# Is there a PostgreSQL function that let's me take a large string, separate it into substrings, and then only replace items in those substrings?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

schema: fruit_schema

table: fruit_table

.

I have this string in a cell in the column, my_column.

x:y. are text I'm not interested in

```
    <Item>
    <Name>First</Name>
    <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. x:y. </Subject>
    </Item>

    <Item>
    <Name>Second</Name>
    <Subject>x:y. x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. x:y.</Subject>
    </Item>
```

I want to add 'Type: Red' to the First Item.
I've written this query so far:

```
    DO
    $$
    DECLARE
        oldItem varchar := 'Food: Apple.';
        newItem varchar;
    BEGIN
        newItem  = 'Food: Apple. Type: Red.';

        UPDATE 
            fruit_schema.fruit_table AS profile
        SET 
            my_column = REPLACE(my_column, oldItem, newItem)
        WHERE
            profile.my_column ILIKE '%First%</Item>%';
    END$$;
```

However, this is my output:

```
    <Item>
    <Name>First</Name>
    <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. </Subject>
    </Item>

    <Item>
    <Name>Second</Name>
    <Subject>x:y. x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. Type: Red. x:y. x:y.</Subject>
    </Item>
```

The First Item updates properly, but the Second Item gets replaced with a duplicate "Type: Red". Is there anyway I can split this giant string into the First and Second Items, respectively? I'd like to only work on the First substring, from `<Name>First</Name>` to `</Item>`

I'd like to do this for every other Item I want to work on.
I'd like to avoid having to manually count the number of characters in the Items, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `regexp_replace()` function with [negative lookahead](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), for example:

```
# select replace(e'aaa\naaa bbb', 'aaa', 'aaa bbb');
┌─────────────┐
│   replace   │
├─────────────┤
│ aaa bbb    ↵│
│ aaa bbb bbb │
└─────────────┘

# select regexp_replace(e'aaa\naaa bbb', 'aaa(\s+)(?!bbb)', 'aaa bbb\1', 'g');
┌────────────────┐
│ regexp_replace │
├────────────────┤
│ aaa bbb       ↵│
│ aaa bbb        │
└────────────────┘
```

Using your data:

```
# select regexp_replace(
  '<Item><Name>First</Name>
     <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. x:y. </Subject>
   </Item>
   <Item><Name>Second</Name>
     <Subject>x:y. x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. x:y.</Subject>
   </Item>
   <Item><Name>Third</Name>
     <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. x:y. </Subject>
   </Item>',
  'Food: Apple\.(\s+)(?!Type: Red\.)',
  'Food: Apple. Type: Red.\1', 'g');
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                           regexp_replace                            │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ <Item>\n<Name>First</Name>                                         ↵│
│      <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. </Subject>         ↵│
│    </Item>                                                         ↵│
│    <Item>\n<Name>Second</Name>                                     ↵│
│      <Subject>x:y. x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. x:y.</Subject>↵│
│    </Item>                                                         ↵│
│    <Item>\n<Name>Third</Name>                                      ↵│
│      <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. </Subject>         ↵│
│    </Item>                                                          │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

Update: How to replace the text only for particular items:

```
with t(x) as (values('<Item><Name>First</Name>
     <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. x:y. </Subject>
   </Item>
   <Item><Name>Second</Name>
     <Subject>x:y. x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. x:y.</Subject>
   </Item>
   <Item><Name>Third</Name>
     <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. x:y. </Subject>
   </Item>'))
select
    string_agg(
        case
            when xx like any(array['%<Name>Third</Name>%','%<Name>Second</Name>%']) then
                regexp_replace(xx, 'Food: Apple\.(\s+)(?!Type: Red\.)', 'Food: Apple. Type: Red.\1', 'g')
            else xx
        end || '</Item>', e'\n')
from t, unnest(string_to_array(replace(x, e'\n', ''), '</Item>')) as xx
where xx <> '';
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                string_agg                                                 │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ <Item><Name>First</Name>     <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. x:y. </Subject>   </Item>                        ↵│
│    <Item><Name>Second</Name>     <Subject>x:y. x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. x:y.</Subject>   </Item>↵│
│    <Item><Name>Third</Name>     <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. </Subject>   </Item>           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. This example helped me a lot. One more question, what if I don't want the Third item to have Food: Apple. Type: Red ?

How would I modify your code to exclude the Third Item, but keep the change in the First Item?

Comment: Let's also say there are 4th, 5th, 6th, n number of items. I want to modify certain items and leave others alone.

Comment: @Tim Then you need to work with XML, not just with string (text representation). https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html But it is yet another big subject.

Comment: Thank you sir! I didn't know this was even an option. I'll look into your link and try to find a solution.

Comment: @Tim Added example how it could be done without using XML functions.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific subject, you can do a `regexp_replace`:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('<Item>
    <Name>First</Name>
    <Subject>x:y. Food: Apple. x:y. </Subject>
    </Item>

    <Item>
    <Name>Second</Name>
    <Subject>x:y. x:y. Food: Apple. Type: Red. x:y. x:y.</Subject>
    </Item>', 'Food: Apple\. ', 'Food: Apple. Type: Red ', '');
```

Maybe you need some adaptations if your replaces are different

Comment: It was my mistake too: without `g` option `regexp_replace` replaces only first occurrence.